# How to change the conversion executable with standalone

Tags: mac, standalone, conversion

I try to use `convert`with the class standalone but the conversion fails because I don't have the necessary tools on my mac. With the last OS the executable convert is `sips`.
I try to install with `brew` `Imagemagic` et `Ghostscript but the installation fails. The question : is it possible to change the executable tool with` \standaloneconfig` ?

In the doc I read this but ...

> The executable name can be change manually using the ‘convertexe’
>   conversion option or by using
>   \standaloneconfig{convert={convertexe={convert}}} in the configuration
>   file ‘standalone.cfg’.

I can use `sips`like this :

```
\immediate\write18{ sips -s format png file.pdf --out file.png }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I write the following `standalone.cfg` file

```latex
\standaloneconfig{
  multi=false,
  crop,
  convert={
    convertexe=sips,
    outext=.png,
    command={%
      \convertexe\space
      -s format png
      \infile\space
      --out \outfile
    }
  }
}
```

then I can run `pdflatex -shell-escape test` on the following file `test.tex`

```latex
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

and the PNG file is produced.

```
> ls -l
total 64
-rw-r--r--  1 staff   221 Jan  7 23:51 standalone.cfg
-rw-r--r--  1 staff    46 Jan  7 23:51 test.aux
-rw-r--r--  1 staff  3522 Jan  7 23:51 test.log
-rw-r--r--  1 staff  9920 Jan  7 23:51 test.pdf
-rw-r--r--@ 1 staff   749 Jan  7 23:51 test.png
-rw-r--r--  1 staff    72 Jan  7 23:50 test.tex
```

Comment: Great ! Perhaps Martin can add this in the documentation.

Comment: @AlainMatthes: Well, it is in the manual. The use of `\standaloneconfig`, all the `convert` options and the possibility of using `standalone.cfg`. Or do you mean adding explicitly the use of `sips`?

Comment: @MartinScharrer it was not obvious for me to find the solution proposed by egreg in the manual but now it's fine. Now with the latest system the only solution on the Mac is to use `sips` so it would be nice to give the solution in your documentation.

Comment: @AlainMatthes Installing ImageMagick with homebrew is very easy.

Comment: I prefer your solution and as I wrote in my question I was unable to install ImageMagick

Comment: @AlainMatthes: Well, I agree the manual could be improved, but creating good manuals is an art for itself. People should happy that all features are mentioned. Saying that, I was planning to add some "How to do X" for the most important cases for a while now. Maybe I come finally around to it.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Well I understand you very well about the documentation. I've been trying to finish one for two months. And then in case of difficulty you can always ask a question!